# How can i get column name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm user of SAP v9.2 (SQL Server 2008). I need to get data of name and result by date and shift in 1 single row, but when I try to use this query :

```
SELECT              
    A.DATE,         
    SUM((ISNULL(A.HASIL_SHIFT1,0) AS HASIL_SHIFT1,          
    SUM((ISNULL(A.HASIL_SHIFT2,0) AS HASIL_SHIFT2,          
    SUM((ISNULL(A.HASIL_SHIFT3,0) AS HASIL_SHIFT3,          
    A.NAME          
FROM                
    (SELECT         
         A.DATE,        
         CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=1 THEN A.HASIL END AS HASIL_SHIFT1,      
         CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=2 THEN A.HASIL END AS HASIL_SHIFT2,      
         CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=3 THEN A.HASIL END AS HASIL_SHIFT3,      
         A.NAME     
    FROM            
        (SELECT     
             A.DATE,    
             A.SHIFT    
             A.HASIL    
             B.NAME 
         FROM       
             (SELECT DISTINCT
                  DATE AS DATE,
                  SHIFT AS SHIFT,
                  QTY AS HASIL
              FROM  
                  TABLE T1
              WHERE 
                  DATE BETWEEN [%0] AND [%1]) A 
        LEFT JOIN   
            (SELECT DISTINCT
                 POSTING_DATE AS DATE
                 SHIFT AS SHIFT
                 NAMA AS NAME
             FROM   
                 TABLE T2) B ON A.DATE = B.DATE 
                             AND A.SHIFT = B.SHIFT) A) A
```

I get result like this :

```
DATE        HASIL_SHIFT1    HASIL_SHIFT2    HASIL_SHIFT3    NAME
07.01.18    202.34          0.00            0.00            Arip Purnomo
07.01.18    0.00            217.86          0.00            Prayitno C Prayitno C
07.01.18    0.00            0.00            205.22
```

it is possible for me to get data with column name format can be same as sum of qty  like this :

```
DATE        HASIL_SHIFT1    HASIL_SHIFT2    HASIL_SHIFT3    NAME_SHIFT1     NAME_SHIFT2             NAME_SHIFT3
07.01.18    202.34          217.86          205.22          Arip Purnomo    Prayitno C Prayitno C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT      
    A.DATE, 

    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=1 THEN A.HASIL END),0) AS HASIL_SHIFT1,       
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=2 THEN A.HASIL END),0) AS HASIL_SHIFT2,       
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=3 THEN A.HASIL END),0) AS HASIL_SHIFT3,       

    MAX(CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=1 THEN B.NAME END) AS NAME_SHIFT1,  
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=2 THEN B.NAME END) AS NAME_SHIFT2,  
    MAX(CASE WHEN A.SHIFT=3 THEN B.NAME END) AS NAME_SHIFT3  

FROM        
    (   
      SELECT  
          DISTINCT
          DATE AS DATE,
          SHIFT AS SHIFT,
          QTY AS HASIL

      FROM    
          TABLE T1

      WHERE   
          DATE BETWEEN [%0] AND [%1]
    ) A 

    LEFT JOIN   

    (   
      SELECT  
          DISTINCT
          POSTING_DATE AS DATE,
          SHIFT AS SHIFT,
          NAMA AS NAME

      FROM    
          TABLE T2
    ) B 

    ON  
    A.DATE=B.DATE   
    AND A.SHIFT=B.SHIFT 

GROUP BY A.DATE
```

Comment: @IpanUtomo If that solves your problem, then please accept that as the correct answer.